# Get value from respone of console in react-native

Tags: parameter-passing

I get response from API and below is screen-shot of console.log.
I need `CategoryName` (highlighted in screen-shot) from console.log.

[image]

This is my code:

> .then((res2) => res2.data)
>
> ```
>          .then(data => {
>             console.log(data);    
>             console.log(data.CategoryName);
>         })
> ```

Please help me.

**EDIT**:

```
console.log(data.EntriesPerPage); // This works. First row of respone

console.log(data.CategoryName); // NOT WORK

console.log(data[0].CategoryName);// NOT WORK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see `data.Data` is an array and you want to access the first row. So try this:

`console.log(data.Data[0].CategoryName);`

Comment: I am indebted to you :)

Answer (score 0):

the data is array. so what you need to do is `data[0].CategoryName`

Comment: Please check EDIT and you will have better idea. I thought it might be simple but really wasted my hours.

Answer (score 0):

`Data` field name is capitalized, so you can access it via `Data[0].CategoryName`, e.g. `console.log(Data[0].CategoryName)`

Comment: Thank you for answer its solved now with help from @freeall